# Audio Recorder Error

Tags: android, audio, recorder

I am trying to make a voice recorder .when i am clicking on record button it gives error as 
        FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: rishabh.agarwal.holmes.recorder, PID: 22175
                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                       at android.media.MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(Native Method)
                                                       at rishabh.agarwal.holmes.recorder.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:47)

this is my code

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button btnPlay,btnRec,btnStop;
MediaRecorder mr;
String fname;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    fname=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/myrec1.3gp";
    btnPlay=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btnRec=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
    btnStop=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
    btnPlay.setEnabled(false);
    btnStop.setEnabled(false);
    btnPlay.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


        }
    });

    btnRec.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mr = new MediaRecorder();
            mr.setOutputFile(fname);
            mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            mr.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.AMR_NB);
            mr.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            try {
                mr.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), 5).show();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
               // Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.toString(), 5).show();
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mr.start();
            btnRec.setEnabled(false);
            btnStop.setEnabled(true);
        }
    });

    btnStop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            mr.release();
            mr.stop();

        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: If you recording file as 3gp format try this one:-              recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

Answer (score 0):

Try removing this line

```
mr.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
```

Comment: when i am trying to remove the above line i got an error as                  try to set the audio encoder without setting the audio source first
01-27 22:24:42.527 12855-12855/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                   Process: rishabh.agarwal.holmes.recorder, PID: 12855
                                                   java.lang.IllegalStateException
                                                       at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(Native Method)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:-

recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
            recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to put permission in manifest file. Write below code in manifest file.

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"></uses-permission>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
```

Comment: i have added the permissions.

Answer (score 0):

> java.lang.IllegalStateException at android.media.MediaRecorder.setOutputFormat

Looking at [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.html#setOutputFormat(int)) we find:

> `public void setOutputFormat (int output_format)`
>
> **Throws**
>   `IllegalStateException` **if it is called** after `prepare()` or **before `setAudioSource()`**/`setVideoSource()`.

In your code you call `setOutputFormat` before `setAudioSource`, which is explicitly stated as resulting in an exception being thrown.